# Equivalence between Quadratic Discriminants and solutions to $n=\pi\overline{\pi}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'm trying to understand the Atkin-Morain Elliptic Curve Primality test, partly using this [master's thesis](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~kant/publications/diplom/uzunkol_2004_master.pdf). At one point there is a lemma stating:

Let $D$ be an imaginary quadratic disciminant $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. There exists $\pi\in O_D$ with $n=\pi\overline{\pi}$ if and only $4n=t^2+Dy^2$ has a solution $(t,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

In this notation, $O_D$ is the set of all algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$. So as far as I can tell, an arbitrary element $\pi\in O_D$ will have the form $\pi = \frac{p}{q}+\sqrt{D}\frac{r}{s}$, with $gcd(p,q)=gcd(r,s)=1$. Thus if $n=\pi\overline{\pi}$ then $n=\frac{p^2}{q^2}+D\frac{r^2}{s^2}$. So one direction is easy: If $4n=t^2+Dy^2$, then set $\pi=\frac{t}{2}+\sqrt{D}\frac{y}{2}$. In the other direction, I don't know where to go.

It seems like I'm including too much with the form of $\pi$, since there is the extra requirement that $\pi$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know how ot use that for the required equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is $\pi\in O_D$ with $n=\pi\overline{\pi}$.  Consider 2 cases depending on whether $D\equiv 0$ or $1\bmod 4$.  First $D\equiv 1\bmod 4$ then $\pi = \frac{t+y\sqrt{D}}{2}$, so that $n=N(\pi)= \frac{t^2+Dy^2}{4}$ and hence $4n =t^2+Dy^2$ as desired.  If $D\equiv 0\bmod 4$ then $\pi=t+y\sqrt{D/4}$ and $n = N(\pi)= t^2+D/4y^2$, so that we can take $4n = 4t^2+Dy^2$.

For the other direction suppose $4n = t^2+Dy^2$, then $\alpha = \frac{t+y\sqrt{D}}{2}$ is an algebraic integer in the case of $D\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and has $N(\alpha)=n$.  If $D\equiv 0\bmod 4$, we see that $t$ must be even, so that $n=(t/2)^2+Dy^2$, and we can take $\alpha = t/2+y\sqrt{D}$ with $N(\alpha)=n$.

Comment: Why can we assume that $\pi=\frac{t+y\sqrt{D}}{2}$? Why not, e.g., $\pi=\frac{t+y\sqrt{D}}{3}$?

Comment: @SamJaques  by hypothesis $\pi\in O_D$ and the integral bases for rings of integers in a quadratic field are well known and are those I've given.  If $\pi=\frac{t+y\sqrt{D}}{3}$ then in general $\pi$ won't satisfy a monic equation over $\Bbb{Z}$ and hence isn't integral.

Comment: Huh, okay. I'll look into the structure of rings of integers in quadratic fields.

Answer (score 0):

when the discriminant is $1 \pmod 4$ the norm is $x^2 + xy + k y^2$ for appropriate $k.$ While it is true that every value of $u^2 + (4k-1)v^2$ is a value of the norm, the reverse need not hold. However,
$$ 4(x^2 + xy + k y^2) = 4x^2 + 4xy + 4k y^2 = (2x+y)^2 + (4k-1)y^2 $$